# too many links in /var/lib/docker error while building Docker container

Tags: docker

Someone suggested on SO to post here. Reposting from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024392/too-many-links-in-var-lib-docker-error-while-building-docker-container

---

Trying to run `docker-compose build` and getting the following error:

> ERROR: ...
>   evalSymlinksInScope: too many links in
>   /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a476d12eaac1c1e3cc684c992cf829b61b999959fd7d23d5a27120dbfd43e178/merged/opt/api/resources

I searched online and have tried running the following commands, but nothing works:

```
docker network prune
docker images prune
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

If I run `ln -ls /var/lib`, there is nothing in this folder about `/docker`. Is this referring to the Docker container? If so, how can this be, when I am in the process of building it. Any ideas on how to resolve this would be great, thank you.

Comment: prune commands mentioned in this question worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, I fixed it going to

Docker -> Troubleshoot -> Reset to factory defaults

Warning: All containers and volumes will be deleted

Answer (score 1):

The error "too many links" usually means that there is a symbolic link pointing to itself, and is not specific to docker.

To find out what happens, use the `namei` command, usually part of `util-linux`.

```
namei /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a476d12eaac1c1e3cc684c992cf829b61b999959fd7d23d5a27120dbfd43e178/merged/opt/api/resources
```

You should see output similar to this, with an indication about too many link levels somewhere in the path.

```
f: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a476d12eaac1c1e3cc684c992cf829b61b999959fd7d23d5a27120dbfd43e178/merged/opt/api/resources
 d /
 d var
 d lib
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks @RalfFriedl. I think this `namei` command in not available on Macs, right?I installed it using `brew`, but I only see messages about the missing `docker` directory, i.e. `ERROR on file docker No such file or directory (2)`. I was building this container just hours before it happened and the code changes I made were not related to the Docker config/files. If I am building the Docker container, then there is no container to ssh into to look around, so I am confused as to where these links are.

Comment: If `/var/lib/docker` doesn't exist, then there can't be an error about too many links. Maybe your docker environment or the shell you use to investigate use different roots/containers?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to deploy a nodejs app via `docker-compose` from windows to a debian VPS using `--context` and got the same issue with apparently no reason

I tried all of the solutions above, clear both images cache and build cache and still nothing worked, Then I figured out that my desktop version of docker was upgraded automatically, so I decided to upgrade docker in my VPS too and everything ran smoothly.

So I guess it's because something with the docker internal building process changed, something regarding to storage driver, and that caused breaking changes between versions but I'm not sure. I hope this can at least help to find a more specific solution.

Here the guide I followed to upgrade docker in a debian https://docs.wavemaker.com/learn/on-premise/upgrade/docker-upgrade/